# Finding average for group of rows that have same string value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the average of colums D10, D50, D90, that have the same string[-8,-2] in 'Sample_Name'. It is: *P1_SUP*, *P1_0.2*, *P1_0.4* and so on.

```
    D10     D50     D90     Sample_Name
1   4.46    19.81   45.32   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
2   2.72    14.22   38.41   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
3   2.3     12.05   27.58   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
4   6.21    19.81   45.32   TIGR01_P1_SUP_2
5   3.78    16.78   32.55   TIGR01_P1_SUP_2
6   3.2     14.22   32.55   TIGR01_P1_0.2_1
7   2.72    12.05   27.58   TIGR01_P1_0.2_1
8   5.27    19.81   38.41   TIGR01_P1_0.2_2
9   3.78    14.22   32.55   TIGR01_P1_0.2_2
10  6.21    23.37   53.48   TIGR01_P1_0.4_1
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .

expected output:

    Av_D10  Av_D50  Av_D90  Sample_Name
1    3.89   16.53   37.84    P1_SUP
2    3.74   15.07   32.77    P1_0.2
3    6.21   23.37   53.48    P1_0.4
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
```

For that, I tried to use `pandas.Series.str` with `groupby`.

```
new_df = df.groupby(df["Sample_Name"].str[-8:-2]).mean()
print(new_df)
```

but yields an error:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: Your code is working for me. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: it's 1.0.1, I've seen there is 1.0.5 available
Is it relevant?